# Setting a variable via the sessions once logged in

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables

Logging in we of course have set the **$_SESSION['username']** and **$_SESSION['password']** as usual. However I am then trying to pack that into a variable for use around the site:

```
$logged = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$_SESSION['username']' AND password = '$_SESSION['password']'");
$logged = mysql_fetch_array($logged);
```

One previous setups, this has enabled me to then use $logged around the site for various reasons, such as calling the logged in users email to echo in a form,

However, this time, when using this method, it fails to echo anything. I have tried using the session username variable which works to echo the username, but then I tried using the session to echo the email and it didn't work.

If someone could help me pinpoint why this is, I'd be grateful.
It just doesn't seem to be pulling any information from the user as it should.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on variable interpolation? Have you `echo`d the SQL query somewhere to see how it's being rendered?

Comment: Please, please please do not store passwords in plain text!

Comment: it's stored MD5 - could that be why this isn't working? Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

For me this just seems like an escape-thing. Try

```
$logged = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND password = '".$_SESSION['password']."'");
$logged = mysql_fetch_array($logged);
```

Also make sure to call `session_start();` before sending any headers/echoing anything if you weren't aware.

### Off topic-tip

As long as this query isn't used in anything public, it's fine. But if you're gonna use this code for anything, be sure to slash your query variables. If not, and if my credentials are not validated nor hashed, you could do some nasty SQL injection by setting your password to be something like `'; DELETE * FROM USERS;#` as the query would then say `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='JohnDoe' AND password = ''; DELETE * FROM USERS;#'`

Comment: I've tried this, but it still failed to show anything when using it to echo information. It seems to be that it's just coming back blank.

Comment: Try `var_dump`'ing your `$logged` and `$_SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 0):

for the usage of session

```
if(!session_id())
    session_start();
```

the above session start is a must in every page.

use `print_r($_SESSION);` to check the session variables initialized..

once done (try using mysqli insted of mysql)

```
$sql='SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE condition';

$rs=$conn->query($sql);

if($rs === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
foreach($arr as $row) {
  echo $row['co1'];
}
```

comment your progress for further changes..